# Facing Login and Registration 500 internal server Error

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

Facing Login and Registration 500 internal server Error

System log - in /chroot/home/campusma/campusmall.in/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

Answer (score 0):

Check any recently edited XML files, a space at the start of the XML file (before `<?xml`) will trigger this error. Layout XML files etc. (likely customer.xml by what you've said above)

you can find the file by editing the file `lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php`

in fuction:
`public function loadFile($filePath)`

add:
`Mage::log('XML_FILE: ' . $filePath);`

reload the site, the culprit file will now be in `mage_root/var/log/system.log`